# Strongly Typed ASP.NET MVC DropDownList Without SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

Is there a way to remove the selectlist parameter below and still use the HTML Helper?  I like the strongly typed option, but use knockout.js quite a bit.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProgramId, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<ProgramModel>()), new { data_bind = "enable: programs().length > 0, value: programId, options: programs, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id', optionsCaption: ' -- Choose Program -- ', event: { change: function(_,event) { getLicenseProductsForProgram() } }" })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The standard DropDownList/DropDownListFor helpers expect an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` as second argument. Obviously there should be nothing preventing you from writing a custom helper, or custom editor template.

Answer (score 2):

Since Drop down List actually needs to have list of options, it requires the selectlist parameter. You can always pass an empty list to it though:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProgramId, new List<SelectListItem>(), new { [the rest of your stuff] })
```